# Get NUnit Test Results Report from Teamcity

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a configuration with Teamcity and I want to get the Tests Results Report with powershell after all the tests ran. Some kind of export. From Teamcity interface, I can go to Tests and click Download all tests as CSV but I want to get this with powershell in order to include this report in artifacts.

That test results report is on the disk (I don't know where or in what form it exists), I just want to get it somehow. My problem is not parsing the data, my problem is getting "the data".

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Artifacts" in the General Settings. Just give a path(s), and TC will copy these after each build to own folder (and maintain history.) And you can access these quite nicely from the Projects overview.